# how to match multiple user input with text content using python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, string-matching

I have a program that allow the user to choose the path of files in order to search for keyword.

The program work perfect when user enter one word but it doesn't display anything when he enter more than 1 word.

where is the error in my function?

- x is 1 word user input
- z is more than 1 word
- d in order to create a dictionnary

## code:

```
def HighLight(self,x,TextString,RepX):
        thematch=TextString.replace(x,RepX)
        TheCount=TextString.count(x)
        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str(thematch))
        return thematch     



def MatchFunc(self):            # Function to highlight the found criteria and display it in the right pane
    self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
    self.x = self.lineEditSearch.text().strip()
    TextString=self.ReadingFileContent(self.FileListSelected())
    self.z = ""
    counter = 0 
    self.d = defaultdict(list)  
    self.filename = os.path.basename(self.FileListSelected())

    for counter , myLine in enumerate(self.filename):
        y=list(self.x.split())
        print(y)       

        for self.z in y:                
            RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+self.z+'</b></u>'                
            self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()

            if self.z in TextString:
                self.d[self.z].append(counter + 1)                        
                TextString = self.HighLight(self.z,TextString,RepX)


            elif self.x in TextString:
                RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+self.x+'</b></u>'
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
                self.d[self.x].append(counter + 1)                                        
                self.HighLight(self.x,TextString,RepX)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? for what inputs does it work? when does it throw error?

Comment: it doesn't throw an error but it just doesn't display anything when the user enter more than 1 word... it work for any input type

Comment: Oh dear! `for self.z in y`, this is not how `for` loops work. Please read some documentation first and try your hands at the examples given. This is not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. `if " " in self.x:` is not needed. Just split your input, if there are no black spaces, it will return a `list` with one `element`
2. No need to pass `sep=" "` to `split`, this is default behaviour
3. Duplicate code: Once you do above two, you will not have a need of `if-else` loop. First `split`, `self.x` and then `for` loop on `y`.

As to why it is not working for multi-inputs, it is probably due to:

```
TextString = self.HighLight(self.z,TextString,RepX)
```

In `else`, you are nt storing the `return` value from this, but can only say for sure, if you show us what `self.HighLight` does.

**Update:**

You are checking `self.z in TextString:` in `if` loop, whereas in `else` your check is `self.x in TextString`. `self.z` is an `empty` string. is that intentional? Why don't you have same check in both the cases?
As per your question, you are expecting your code to have same behaviour when user gives multiple inputs, in that case, you should have same logic for both cases.

Hence, my first suggestion to remove duplicate code.

Comment: i will edit my question and add the highlight function.

Comment: i tried your answer and get rid off if else  and delete sep =" "  but still when i try to enter multi-inputs doesn't work

Comment: first i deleted the if else statement as you suggested----
second i did not understand what you mean have the same logic for both cases

Comment: **x** is for the first input--- 
**z** is for second input

Comment: **z** is `""`, which is an empty string. how can it be input

Comment: so based on your answer i just need to check `if self.x in TextString` right ?

Comment: i will edit my question and add the updated function